# Solving recurrence of divide and conquer using master theorem

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence, divide-and-conquer, master-theorem

Can T(n) = 3T(n/2) + c T(1)=0, solved using master theorem? If yes, I am struggling on understand master theorem now, could someone tell me which case it falls to and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different possible approaches for the master theorem. I like the one proposed by Cormen et al. in their book *Introduction to Algorithms*.

1. If f(n) = O(n^(log*b*(a-e))) for some constant e>0, then **T(n) = Θ(n^(log*b*(a)))**
2. If f(n) = Θ(n^(log*b*(a))), then **T(n) = Θ(n^(log*b*(a)) . lg n)**
3. If f(n) = Ω(n^(log*b*(a+e))) for some constant e>0, and if a.f(n/b) < c.f(n) for
   some constant c<1 and all sufficiently large n, then **T(n) = Θ(f(n))**

Now we need to compare **f(n)** with **n^(log*b*(a))** .

- if **f(n)** is *polynomially* smaller than **n^(log*b*(a))**, it
  falls under the 1st case
- if **n^(log*b*(a))** is *polynomially* smaller than **f(n)**, it
  falls under the 3rd case
- if **f(n)** and **n^(log*b*(a))** are the same size, it falls under
  the 2nd case

Note that the three cases do not cover all the possibilities for f(n). There is
a gap between cases 1 and 2 when f(n) is smaller than **n^(log*b*(a))** but not polynomially smaller. Similarly, there is a gap between cases 2 and 3 when f(n) is larger
than **n^(log*b*(a))** but not polynomially larger. If the function f(n) falls into one of these
gaps, or if the regularity condition in case 3 fails to hold, you cannot use the master
method to solve the recurrence.

Now to solve the recurrence in question...

a=3, b=2, f(n) = c = n^0

so we have n^(log2(3)) ≈ n^(1.58) which is polynomially larger than n^0, falling under the 1st case. Then the time complexity is **T(n) = Θ(n^(log*b*(a)))** --> **T(n) = Θ(n^1.58)**